# How to Unmarshal a rdf xml using golang?

Tags: xml, go, rdf

I can can Unmarshal simple xmls but when i try to Unmarshal rdf xml, i dont't get anything.

Currently i need to parse the below xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='about'
  xmlns:et='http://ns.exiftool.org/1.0/' et:toolkit='Image::ExifTool 12.30'
  xmlns:ExifTool='http://ns.exiftool.org/ExifTool/1.0/'
  xmlns:System='http://ns.exiftool.org/File/System/1.0/'
  xmlns:File='http://ns.exiftool.org/File/1.0/'>
 <ExifTool:ExifToolVersion>12.30</ExifTool:ExifToolVersion>
 <System:FileSize>20 MiB</System:FileSize>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

below is the `go` code that i am using to parse the xml:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type MyXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rdf:RDF"`
    Rdf     string   `xml:"rdf,attr"`
}

func main() {
    // Open our xmlFile
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("./z.xml")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened z.xml")
    // defer the closing of our xmlFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    // read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var data MyXml

    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &data)

    fmt.Println(data)

}
```

And no matter what i set `XMLName` i always get `{{ } }`.

I need `System:FileSize` but getting nothing in data.

Comment: The error, if you would check it, would tell you what the problem is. Functions that return an error do not do it for fun. The errors are intended to be handled by the caller. Explicitly. Please, do not ignore them.

Comment: @mkopriva i am getting this:`expected element type <rdf:RDF> but have <RDF>` but i do have `rdf:RDF`, `XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rdf:RDF"``. don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You are interpreting the error message in reverse: it is "expected element type <rdf:RDF>" based on the struct field type, "but have <RDF>" element in the XML. i.e. do this: https://go.dev/play/p/gAGyT0yiibD

Comment: Thanks! that worked, but i need it using namespaces. It works when i use `Description>FileSize` but not when i try `Description>System:FileSize`.

Comment: Namespaces in the struct field tags must be provided using their full **namespace-url**, and namespaces don't work with the "descend" format of the struct tags, so you'll have to nest the FileSize in another struct. See: https://go.dev/play/p/EiFadx8jiFH